# How to find rectangle with a given aspect ratio inside a triangle

Tags: geometry, aspect-ratio

Assume the following three things are known:

- The (x,y) coordinate of point A (the top left point in each of the example triangles shown below),
- The slope and y-intercept of the line shown in green,
- An aspect ratio for the target rectangle.

...I would like to find out how to determine the location of the point shown in yellow--which intersects the green line--such that the rectangle shown in black matches the required target aspect ratio.

Thank you.

-lagouyn

[image: Three example triangles]

Answer (score 0):

Let's A point has coordinates (ax, ay), and line equation is `y=y0+k*x`
Then

```
(y0 + k*X - ay) * aspect = X - ax
X * (k*aspect - 1) = ay*aspect - ax - y0*aspect
X = (ay*aspect - ax - y0*aspect) / (k*aspect - 1)
Y = y0+ k*X
```

Comment: Hi MBo. Thanks for your reply! I had to modify your calculation slightly in order to get a correct result. The change was to use the negative of "aspect" instead of aspect. Regards, -lagouyn